# List of Python Dataframe column values meeting criteria in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2, which have a common column heading, Name. The Name values are unique within df1 and df2. df1's Name values are a subset of those in df2; df2 has more rows -- about 17,300 -- than df1 -- about 6,900 -- but each Name value in df1 is in df2. I would like to create a list of Name values in df1 that meet certain criteria in other columns of the corresponding rows in df2.

#### Example:

#### df1:

|  | Name | Age | Hair |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Jim | 25 | black |
| 1 | Mary | 58 | brown |
| 3 | Sue | 15 | purple |

#### df2:

|  | Name | Country | phoneOS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Shari | GB | Android |
| 1 | Jim | US | Android |
| 2 | Alain | TZ | iOS |
| 3 | Sue | PE | iOS |
| 4 | Mary | US | Android |

I would like a list of only those Name values in df1 that have df2 Country and `phoneOS` values of US and Android. The example result would be [Jim, Mary].

I have successfully selected rows within one dataframe that meet multiple criteria in order to copy those rows to a new dataframe. In that case pandas/Python does the iteration over rows internally. I guess I could write a "manual" iteration over the rows of df1 and access df2 on each iteration. I was hoping for a more efficient solution whereby the iteration was handled internally as in the single-dataframe case. But my searches for such a solution have been fruitless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```py
df_1.loc[df_1.Name.isin(df_2.loc[df_2.Country.eq('US') & \
                                 df_2.phoneOS.eq('Android'), 'Name']), 'Name']
```

Result:

```
0     Jim
1    Mary
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

if you want the result as a list just add `.to_list()` at the end

Comment: Thanks! I've tested this and it works.

Comment: But the abstracted solution doesn't work with my real data. The only possibly relevant difference that I can see are that the two dataframes are much larger (as indicated in my question), have more columns, and they come from external sources via URLs. But they both look fine when saved as .csv files. So there's some relevant difference I am _not_ seeing. I'm stumped on how to debug this, so I may post another question. NB I did really test your solution via copy from here and paste into a .py after instantiating the example df1 and df2 therein.

Comment: do you get an error or does it just takes to much time? you should also check that the column names don't have spaces or are repeated because else you have write the command different

Comment: I immediately get `Series([], Name: ticker, dtype: object)` i.e., no data.

Comment: P.S. I did post [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73210239/list-dataframe-column-values-meeting-criteria-in-other-dataframe-need-debug-sug). ... The column names are not repeated and have no spaces.

Comment: I knew it had to be a head-slapper -- I just noticed that the relevant column name is all uppercase in one dataframe and all lowercase in the other!

Comment: I deleted the other question mentioned in the comment before last, because my difficulty was due to the upper-lower case issue and my basic question was answered here. One additional note: there were a few duplicate key column values in the smaller dataframe -- the "df_2" of this answer. This answer's approach did not produce duplicates in the output list.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = df1.merge(df2, on='Name')

data.loc[((data.phoneOS == 'Android') & (data.Country == "US")), 'Name'].values.tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tested this and it works. @99_m4n's answer does also, and since I can accept only one I'm accepting that one on the almost-arbitrary basis that it was posted 6 minutes earlier.

Comment: @brec so, at least upvote it :)

Comment: Oops, yes -- upvoted! Meanwhile, your solution works in an actual .py with the example data, but doesn't work with my real data. I didn't get farther than the `merge` statement. My `merge` returns a `data` that consists only of the column names with no rows. The column names look as I'd expect the merged ones to look. I experimented with various parameters to `merge`, and also tried  `join`, to no avail. I was able to get data rows, but "too many" -- not the selected rows (of which there are 3 with your code and the example data). Cf. my comment to @99_m4n's answer for some additional context.